# Anychart Bar Chart Format and xAxis Label

Tags: javascript, html, anychart

https://jsfiddle.net/wvzechu0/

```
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    
      // data
      var data = [
        ["Chocolate paste", 5],
        ["White honey", 2],
        ["Strawberry jam", 2],
        ["Condensed milk", 1]
      ];
    
      // set chart type
      chart = anychart.bar(data);
    
      // set chart title
      chart.title("Food Shortage");
    
      // display chart
      chart.container("container").draw();
});
```

Currently am moving from `ChartJS` to `AnyChart` as chartjs does not have the thing that i needed.

But currently i met a problem is that (in the example) jsfiddle , how do i :

1. Set a Precision Number on xAxis Label (for example, in xAxis show 1,2,3,4,5 instead of 2,4,6)
2. Is that possible for Anychart to change the labelling ?
   for example : 1 = shortage  , 2 = need restock, 3 = medium , 4 = enough stock, 5 = fully stocked

Added Example in the image : https://prnt.sc/OK35IkjAV_Nv

Answer (score 0):

1. you can change tick interval https://docs.anychart.com/Axes_and_Grids/Scales#minor_and_major
2. you can format labels via function https://playground.anychart.com/pDke3imP